# Discord.py Bot edits the message after clicking its reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been looking for this code to get to work:

```
    ...
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction(":arrow_left:")
    await message.add_reaction(":arrow_right:")

    async def on_reaction(reaction, user):
        if user.reaction.emoji == ":arrow_left:":
            await message.edit("Page left")
            
        if user.reaction.emoji == ":arrow_right:":
            await message.edit("Page right")
```

Basically the bot reacts to its' own embed message. And I want let it edit the embed when clicking on the reaction that the bot added. That's where I want to use the *temporary* "on_reaction" in order to make it only work for this embed message.

Yours truly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DiscordUtils` and work with the built-in paginator.

**Here is a simple example:**

```py
import DiscordUtils as DiscordUtils

embed1 = discord.Embed(color = ctx.author.color, title="Test") # Add anything you want to
embed2 = [...]
embed3 = [...]

paginator = DiscordUtils.Pagination.CustomEmbedPaginator(ctx, remove_reactions=True)
paginator.add_reaction('⏮️', "first")
paginator.add_reaction('⏪', "back")
paginator.add_reaction('⏩', "next")
paginator.add_reaction('⏭️', "last")
paginator.add_reaction('', "lock")

embeds = [embed1, embed2, embed3]
await paginator.run(embeds)
```

*For more information see: [DiscordUtils](https://pypi.org/project/DiscordUtils/)*